# How to remove all the items under "Personal Options" on user profile page?

Tags: customization

Under "Personal Options" on user profile page, there are:
(1) disable visual editor
(2) admin color scheme
(3) keyboard shortcuts
(4) show admin bar

I can remove admin color scheme using remove_action, but not the rest.

Is there a way to remove them all at once? Or one by one using remove_action or style or js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the kind of thing you had in mind.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-profile.php', 'remove_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-user-edit.php', 'remove_profile_fields' );

function remove_profile_fields( $hook ) {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        form#your-profile p+h3,
        form#your-profile p+h3+table { display:none!important;visibility:hidden!important; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

There aren't any actions or filters to remove the items you're referring to(with exception the admin color scheme), and the table they sit in does not have a unique identifier, which in turn means the only solution to getting rid of them is using CSS or jQuery selectors, neither of which will work for *every* user.

IE6 for example won't understand the CSS i've written above and will just ignore it.

jQuery solutions are possible, but like the above, they won't work for *every* user.

@Jeremy,
Whilst it's nice you've shown how to add a stylesheet to the admin, it's not really ideal to suggest adding one to **every** admin page when the requirement was to only load additional CSS or JS for a specific one or two pages, you should ideally also be using `plugins_url()` for generating the URL to plugin files.

Comment: @t3los, thanks for the tips. I appreciate the honest comment.

Comment: Thank you for this intermediary solution, it's good enough for the time being.

Comment: @t31os I've seen a core ticket in [wordpress trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12295). I think wordpress 3.4 will have hook to remove them without using css. [Check this patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/12295/12295.diff) Can you tell me what code i should use to remove it if apply that patch? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works. I made a simple plug-in for customizing the WordPress Admin area. Just save this code as custom_admin.php and put it in a folder named custom_admin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Admin
Plugin URI: http://ideatree-website-design.com/
Description: Creating a Better Looking WordPress Admin Screen
Version: 1.0
Author: Jeremy Jared
Author URI: http://ideatree-website-design.com/
*/
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'load_custom_admin_css' );

function load_custom_admin_css()
{
wp_enqueue_style('my_style', WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/custom_admin/custom_admin.css');
} 
?>
```

Next create a style-sheet and name it custom_admin.css and place this code in the file:

```
.form-table th, label, #your-profile label + a, #postcustomstuff table, #your-profile fieldset, #rightnow, div.dashboard-widget, #dashboard-widgets p.dashboard-widget-links, #replyrow #ed_reply_toolbar input {
display:none !important;
}
```

Place the custom_admin.php and the custom_admin.css in the custom_admin folder, 
upload it to your plug-ins folder.

You can then activate it inside the plug-ins section. To make changes just go to plug-ins>edit> and choose the custom_admin plugin to add or remove css. This can also be used to customize the look of the admin area.

Comment: I know this part of the code. I actually need the hook if remove_action, the class or id if css for those items, which I cannot quite pinpoint. Of course, hook is cleaner.

Comment: I don't know the hook, but the css i Provided are the ID's and class's for the items.

Comment: I've checked the ID and classes, they don't match. There is no individual id or classes that can be used to remove the label and the h3 personal options header.